# Migrating data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, data-migration

I am working on an application and I need to move the Stripe payment data I have saved around in my user model. I am looking for the best way of doing this. My current data is stored at `user.stripe.<value>` but I want to move it to `user.company.stripe.<value>`

Is there tools out there that can handle moving this data around for me or will I need to create a tool to handle this myself? I will be doing a decent amount of this type of data movement during a major refactor (more like a rewrite) so making a tool if non exists is okay with me just no idea how to migrate the data and other Stack Overflow posts are not being of much use that I have found.

Probably picked a bad day/time to post too... Hopefully someone can help me out with examples or direction on where to go from here.

**What I want the data to look like:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b89c571d855a23b5b07fe95"), "company" : { "customForms" : [ ], "subUserCount" : 1, "stripe" : { "plan" : "<plan Name>", "customerId" : "cus_<ID>", "last4" : "4242", "subscriptionId" : "sub<ID>", "isCoupon" : false } }, "email" : "john.doe@example.ca", "password" : "$2a$10$gMbdy5Dh9Ym..xbVAvhaJO2xhVARAL3oXvad/fX4zAcCuZB88tR1C", "role" : "company", "companyID" : "da89bdee-4123-444c-b221-d41212320a90",  }
```

**Current data format:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b89c571d855a23b5b07fe95"), "company" : { "customForms" : [ ], "subUserCount" : 1 }, "stripe" : { "plan" : "testplan2", "customerId" : "cus_<ID>", "last4" : "4242", "subscriptionId" : "sub_<ID>", "isCoupon" : false }, "isVerified" : true, "email" : "john.doe@example.ca", "password" : "$2a$10$gMbdy5Dh9Ym..xbVAvhaJO2xhVARAL3oXvad/fX4zAcCuZB88tR1C", "role" : "company", "companyID" : "da89bdee-4123-444c-b221-d41212320a90" }
```

Comment: can you provide sample of your data. An update will probably do the job

Comment: @matthPen I updated the OP with the data formats I want.